# Troubles installing catboost in R

Tags: r, reticulate, catboost

I keep getting the error message:

```
  Warning in file(con, "r") :
     cannot open file 'C:PROGRA~1RR-42~1.2/share/Rd/macros/system.Rd': No such file or directory
   Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
   Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
```

when I try to install catboost in R. I have tried following the docs regarding the installation process but can't get catboost working on R. Here's my code

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON="C:/Users/jasmi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/")
library(reticulate)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.16.5/catboost-R-Windows-0.16.5.tgz')
library(catboost)


boxing <- readRDS('datafullboxingdatasetnew.RDS')
p <- import("pandas")
cat_model <- p$read_pickle("catmodelsummary.pkl")
```

Comment: I was able to install the R package (`devtools::install_url(...)`) without error. Win11, R-4.2.2. Often (usually?) there are warnings or errors included in the text when R attempts to install, can you add everything in between `install_url(..)` and the error?

Comment: When line specifically returns the error? Is it the `devtools::install_url` line? I assume there is some specific reason you are trying to install such an old version of the package (from Aug 20, 2019)?

Comment: @r2evans I added the full error to the question

Comment: @MrFlick Not really, this project was using the old version (old project), defaulted to trying to install the same version the project used initially

Comment: `share/Rd/macros/system.Rd` is part of the base R installation, so if it's missing or not readable, then there is something amiss with your installation of R. The obsfuscation of the path (that windows does) with `C:PROGRA~1RR-42~1.2` makes it a little difficult to know for sure what's going on there, but frankly that file shouldn't be touched during any package installation, suggesting that the file is not even _readable_. Is R installed by admin, and some files are not world-readable?